# Elles seraient (seront ?) finalement complètement différentes de ce que nous imaginions

Tags: conjugaison, conditionnel, futur

Ce genre de phrase me pose problème à chaque fois que je souhaite placer un peu de suspense dans un texte. Je bloque au niveau de ces phrases que j’utilise pour parler de quelque chose qui se passera (à coup sûr) dans le futur, mais qui se révèlera être une surprise (pas prévu dans le passé).

Dans cette phrase je suis par exemple tenté (non pas grammaticalement, mais à l’intuition) de placer « seraient ». « Seront » me semble perdre une partie de la finesse :

> Ces montagnes seraient finalement complètement différentes de ce que nous imaginions.

Faut il utiliser seraient ou seront dans ce cas ? S’il est possible d’utiliser les deux, quelle est la différence ?

autre exemple :

> Ces montagnes seraient (seront ?) finalement si différentes que nous
>   finirions (finirons ?) par les appeler « les piques ».

Answer (score 5):

En général, l’emploi d'un verbe avec "que + sujet + verbe" marque le subjonctif, or vous utilisez cette forme avec le conditionnel ce qui d'après moi n'est pas correct.

> Que nous finissions

est l'emploi correct du subjonctif.
Si vous désirez néanmoins utiliser le conditionnel, dites simplement :

> *Nous finirions*

(sans le "que" devant)

Pour en revenir à votre question, je crois que si l'action se passe, ou est censée se passer dans le futur et qu'elle est certaine vous devez employer le futur avec les deux verbes.

> Aujourd'hui j'en suis sûr, ces montagnes *seront* finalement si différentes que nous *finirons* par les appeler « les piques ».

Cela dit, si le fait que l’événement se produise est moins certain vous pouvez aussi employer le subjonctif pour en atténuer la certitude:

> Il se pourrait que ces montagnes *soient* finalement si différentes que
>   nous *finissions* par les appeler « les piques ».

Si vous souhaitez tout de même utiliser le conditionnel, qui marquera moins l'improbabilité de l’événement il est également possible d'utiliser *seraient* :

> Seraient-elle finalement si différentes que nous finissions par les
>   appeler « les piques » ?

Ici, l'emploi du subjonctif sur le second verbe force le doute, et son utilisation requiert de placer la phrase à l'interrogatif.

Si néanmoins nous utilisons le conditionnel pour les deux verbes:

> Dès lors que ces montagnes seraient finalement si différentes, nous
>   finirions par les appeler « les piques ».

On voit qu'ici le doute n'est plus permis. Avec le conditionnel toute notion d'improbabilité est enlevée de la phrase, nous exprimons simplement un état suite à une alternative.

En résumé si le subjonctif marque le doute ou l'incertitude, le conditionnel se contente de décrire une possibilité.

Donc comme le suspens est plutôt lié au doute je vous conseille d’utiliser le subjonctif.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia offre des exemples explicites à ce sujet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel#L.27expression_du_futur):

> Dans le discours indirect, la concordance des temps impose que, lorsque la principale est à un temps passé, le conditionnel présent se substitue au futur.

Et:

> Dans un récit dont le temps de narration est au passé, le conditionnel exprime un procès futur par rapport à celui exprimé par le verbe au temps de narration

En fin de compte, le choix entre le futur et le conditionnel dépend du contexte de la phrase:

- au présent, on associe le futur
- au passé, on associe le conditionnel, à valeur de futur dans ce passé.

Les exemples de Wikipedia montrent la différence. Au présent:

> « Jacques annonce que, dès qu'il ne pleuvra plus, il ira chercher des champignons. »

Et au passé (l'exemple «passe bien» à l'imparfait aussi):

> « Jacques annonça que, dès qu'il ne pleuvrait plus, il irait chercher des champignons. »

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas de discours indirect dans les exemples donnés dans la question.

Comment: En effet. La section de Wikipédia couvre aussi le « récit dont le temps de narration est au passé ».

Answer (score 2):

Dans la question que pose Guillaume, il ne sagit pas de concordance de temps mais de nuance dans le sens. Le conditionnel introduit le doute alors que le futur exprime la certitude. Je m'explique: Ces montagnes SERAIENT finalement complètement différentes.... veut dire qu il y a de fortes chances qu'elles le soient, mais nous n'en sommes pas certains. D autre part, ces montagnes SERONT finalement complètement différentes..... veut dire que, sans l'ombre d'un doute, elles le seront.(Nous les imaginions d'une certaine façon mais nous SAVONS maintenant que nous nous trompions).